# Qt - getting photo metadata

Tags: c++, qt, metadata, photos

I want to use QMediaObject to obtain metadata from a photo. Only way to accomplish that seems to be use QMediaPlayer which inherits from QMediaObject and use setMedia method. However it seems that QMediaPlayer reads only video and audio formats. Logically QCamera which inherits from QMediaObject too, should do similiar job with photos, but I cant find way to set any photo. However it must be possible because photos are included in metadata category list http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qmediametadata.html .